# What causes a JRE 6 JVM code cache leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

Since switching to JRE 6, my server's code cache usage (non-heap) keeps growing indefinitely. My application creates a lot of classes at runtime, BUT these classes are successfully unloaded during the GC process. I can see these classes getting unloaded in the gc logs and also the permGen usage stays constant. I specifically make sure in my code that these classes are orphaned once I am finished with them and so they correctly get garbage collected from permGen.

The code cache however keeps growing. I only became aware of the code cache after switching to JRE 6. So I guess my questions are:

1. Does GC include the code cache?
2. What could cause a code cache memory leak, specifically.
3. Is there a bug in JDK 6 in this area?

Comment: have you tried limiting the max size with the -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize runtime flag?

Comment: Hi there. yes I have, it just puts off the inevitable. I guess I am trying to understand what the code cache is used for and how in your code you can cause a memory leak in this specific area of the JVM memory architecture. All other JVM memory segements are getting garbage collected and are stable. Its just the code cache that is rising indefinitely and I dont know why. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an application server to run your code, or running it directly?

Comment: Its running from within our own application server. Once I have generated the code, I create a new classloader and store it - it is at this point that I clear out the store of older classloaders, thereby allowing the gc to unload those old generated classes. Then, when I need one of the objects I pass the new classloader into Class.forName(). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look through this discussion and just go backwards to see what may be helpful in trying to narrow this down:
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-compiler-dev/2009-January/000530.html

This one involves JDK5 but may be helpful:
http://www.nabble.com/Java-code-cache-memory-td22202283.html

Are you using this to compile jsp pages, or something similar?  If not, what is being compiled after the application starts up?  Are you using AspectJ with runtime weaving?

It would help to know what you are doing to get a better idea as to how to help.

Also, when the code cache is exhausted, does it just stop compiling anew or does the jvm crash?  I would expect the former.

Are you using Sun's JDK?  I am guessing you are since I doubt the others are listed as version 6, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Thanks. I am using velocity templates to generate and compile java code periodically in the system. We use a system where the configuration of the system is specified in excel spreadsheets and when the user changes the excel spreadsheets, we re-generate java code based on the configuration and re-compile at runtime, from within the system. Therefore, we have multiple versions of java code. I know these versions are getting gc'd from permGen since I can see it in the gc logs. The JVM crashes, but prob due to poor JVM args. Yes, using JDK 6. Will look at links, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if the new G1 Garbage Collector (as of Java 6 update 14) might help you. You can try it with -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC, however according to [comments on Jon Masamitsu's blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/our_collectors) it won't (if the problem really is due to the code cache). But maybe the discussion there or the links from it might help.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments in this blog post: http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/our_collectors

> code is evicted when classes are unloaded (as
>   well, as when methods are "invalidated", i.e., some assumptions were
>   made during their compilation that do not hold any more)

if I were you I would run a workload, take a heap dump, and check whether all classes are gc'd that you expect to be.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible places i would look for the problem:Leaked Loaders and Massive String interning.

From your app description, i would more likely verify whether old generated classes are being unloaded by the GC.

I dont think jConsole has a way of visualizing this, but if you can get a copy of YourKit, it has a graphical way of detecting both the above problems.

Comment: How would massive string interning interfer with code cache? Strings are stored in perm gen and code cache is a separate region.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to invoke jvisualvm (in the JDK) against the troublesome application?  It may easily make you much wiser about what is happening.

Comment: I use jconcole which tells me everything I need. I know that the code cache is growing indefinitely. I am trying to see why, no visualisation of the JVM code will tell me that I presume? Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. no, but you can use -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing flag to let the JVM dispose some of the compiled code when the code cache fills up, though it's not so useful sometimes. try -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize and -XX:CompileThreshold.
2. hot deployments from time to time, etc.

see more: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/07/useful-jvm-flags-part-4-heap-tuning/